# Return an object at the end after chaining

Tags: javascript, fluid, chaining

I'm trying to make a fluid pattern so that I can chain functions together. Something like this below. But I want to return the object at the end.

```
var foo = new create();
foo.x("hello")
   .y("howdy!")
   .z("hello")
   .get_obj();
```

Right now it seems that I get a pointer/reference to the `create()` function, which is because I’m return this after each function call (I guess?). I know that I can do something like `var bar = foo.obj;` but I’d really appreciate if there was a way to avoid that. I’m fairly new to Javascript, I’ve used Typescript before so my closure knowledge is somewhat limited, if that’s the problem.

```
function create() {
    this.obj = {}

    this.x = function(value) {
        this.obj["key_x"] = value;
        return this;
    }

    this.y = function(value) {
        this.obj["key_y"] = value;
        return this;
    }

    this.z = function(name) {
        this.obj["key_z"] = value;
        return this;
    }

    this.get_obj = function() {
        return this.obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Your code just works does not it?

Comment: `["key_z"]` is a hard way to say `.key_z`

Comment: Yes i know that. I was wondering if there is a way to return the object `this.obj` at the end instead of getting a pointer to the `create()` function.

Comment: You already get the object with `get_obj()`

Comment: Why assign properties to `this.obj` when you can just assign properties to `this`, as in `this["key_x"] = value;`? That way you don't need a `.get_obj()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning the result of the chain to anything, so `foo` remains unchanged and is still the result of `new create()`.

Maybe you mean to do this?

```
var foo = new create()
   .x("hello")
   .y("howdy!")
   .z("hello")
   .get_object();
```

Then `foo` should be the object you expect.

---

It's hard to tell your exact use case from the sample code, but you might write something a little cleaner like this:

```
function Create();
Create.prototype = {
    x: function(value) {
        this["key_x"] = value;
        return this;
    },

    y: function(value) {
        this["key_y"] = value;
        return this;
    },

    z: function(value) {
        this["key_z"] = value;
        return this;
    }
}

var foo = new Create()
   .x("hello")
   .y("howdy!")
   .z("hello");
```

Comment: Can you explain why? I feel like it is the same.

Comment: Also note the `get_obj` (in the function core) and the `get_object` (in the outside) typo.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! It all makes sense now. I feel really stupid for missing that part.

Comment: If you create the functions using `this.x = function` in the constructor then the JS runtime actually makes a new function for every call to `new create()`.  Assigning it to the `prototype` uses JS prototypical inheritance to use the same function instances for all objects. It would be more efficient.